# Camera Touch Zoom and Pan with world - 2D

Tags: unity, 2d, camera

I am doing my first unity2d game and im in need of a little optimization for my camera.

I have a camera which could pan and zoom with the speed i have defined. The problem with that is the speed i defined for panning will be too fast when zoomed in and soo slow when zoomed out. Maybe it could be achieved by having varying speed with zoom level. I dont want that.

Instead, i would like to have the camera used in Clash of Clans (i have seen it only in that).

The camera pans/zooms async with the world.
That is, at any zoom level, if we placed our finger on an object X and started moving, the object X will be right below our fingers all the way. That means the world moves relatively.

Its the same with the zooming.
If we placed two fingers on object X & on object Y and started 'zooming' in or out, 
Those two objects will be there right below the fingers all the way.

### That is what i would like.

For panning, i tried this and failed :
(Unity C#)

`Touch t = Input.getTouch(0); //when touchcount = 1 only`

Vector2 prev_touch_position = t.position - t.deltaPosition;

Vector3 resultant_unitvector = (prev_touch_position - t.position) / (prev_touch_position - t.position).magnitude;

float resultant_magnitude = Info.half_height / camera.orthographicSize * (prev_touch_position - t.position).magnitude;
//Info.half_height is calculated during change in orthographic size and is a static variable.

camera.transform.position += resultant_unitvector * resultant_magnitude;

The above code doesnt work as expected on debugging.

It would be a great help for the community if someone could solve this cuz that is some pretty good camera :)
(Include damping after touch release if you could ? :) )
Im just a student by the way :)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the solution at last :P
the problem was the position of the Touches were in pixels and i took them as for screen coordinates.
So to fix it,

```
float resultant_magnitude = Info.half_height / camera.orthographicSize * (prev_touch_position - t.position).magnitude;
```

replace the above by this :

```
float resultant_magnitude = Info.half_height / (Screen.height / 2) * (prev_touch_position - t.position).magnitude;
```

This helped :)